# How to change the selected word color with POI XWPF

Tags: java, function, apache-poi, textcolor, xwpf

How can i change the selected word font color?
I want to create a function for this, but my level is so basic with this api...

This is my pseudo cod:

```
 public String setTextColor(String word){
     String coloredWord = null;
     /**
     * setColor method here
     */
    return coloredWord;
}
```

So, this function have to return the colored word. 
Please help, if you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Run Property. This works similarly to Rich Text Strings in the Excel API, but is a bit different.

```
// p is your paragraph object
XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
r.setColor("ff0000");
r.setText("This text is red");
r = p.createRun();
r.setText(" but this text is black");
```

All text in a given run has the same formatting properties. Any time those properties need to change, you need to add a new run to the paragraph.