# How to set change font colors by POI

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I use below code to update MS Word by using POI in my selenium scripts.

```
public class WordAutomation {

    public static String projectpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    public static FileOutputStream out;
    public static String ScreenshotPath = projectpath+"\\Screenshots\\";
    public static XWPFDocument docx;
    public static XWPFRun run;
    public static String wordFile;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        docx = new XWPFDocument();
        run = docx.createParagraph().createRun();
        wordFile = ScreenshotPath+"ScreenshotFile.docx";
        out = new FileOutputStream(wordFile);
    
        run.setText("Test Started");
        run.addBreak();
        run.setText("Its a Pass scenario");
        run.addBreak();
        run.setColor("ff0000");//Change the font color to red
        run.setText("Its a Fail scenario");
        run.addBreak();
        run.setColor("000000");//back to black again
        run.setText("Its a Pass scenario");
        docx.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        docx.close();
    }
}
```

I need output like below

[image]

but i am getting output like below

[image]

Please help me to solve my issue. Actually i want to save the document to implement the changes and continue further.

Comment: Not positive, but doesn't one set the text _first_, and only then set the color (and other attributes)? (Not adding it as an answer, since I don't recall for sure if this is how the API works or not)

Comment: i tried all combinations but none of them working. it takes the last font setting by default. as everything is in memory and writes at the end. i need a snippet to save after every write then continue...

Comment: In Word, everything in a Text Run has the same styling. Try creating a different run for the differently styled pieces of text

Comment: Thanks.. i tried different run and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a new run has to be created for each change in style; see link below. This works:

```
    docx = new XWPFDocument();
    wordFile = screenshotPath+"ScreenshotFile.docx";
    out = new FileOutputStream(wordFile);

    p = docx.createParagraph();

    run = p.createRun();
    run.setText("Test Started");
    run.addBreak();

    run = p.createRun();
    run.setText("Its a Pass scenario");
    run.addBreak();

    run = p.createRun();
    run.setColor("FF0000");
    run.setText("Its a Fail scenario");
    run.addBreak();

    run = p.createRun();
    run.setText("Its a Pass scenario");
    run.addBreak();

    docx.write(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    docx.close();
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41681461/127971

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks for your efforts...